# Getting strings of specific length from a string of different length

Tags: c#, .net, substring

I have allowed the user to enter 500 characters into a string. As I am restricted to enter only 100 characters in a key/value pair. I have to make 5 different strings from that string. Maybe user would have entered only 50 characters, or 209 characters. So here's the code:

```
private List<string> MakeCustomDataReadyForPromotion()
{
    var setting = SettingsDbManager.Instance.GetSettingBaseOnTrackId(Settings.PromotionDetailsTrackId);
    var restaurantTitle = setting.PromotionTitle;
    var promotionBody = setting.PromotionBody;
    List<string> message = new List<string>
    {
        restaurantTitle
    };
    if (promotionBody.Length > 400)
    {
        message.Add(promotionBody.Substring(0, 99));
        message.Add(promotionBody.Substring(100, 199));
        message.Add(promotionBody.Substring(200, 299));
        message.Add(promotionBody.Substring(300, 399));
        message.Add(promotionBody.Substring(400, promotionBody.Length - 1));
    }
    else if (promotionBody.Length > 300)
    {
        message.Add(promotionBody.Substring(0, 99));
        message.Add(promotionBody.Substring(100, 199));
        message.Add(promotionBody.Substring(200, 299));
        message.Add(promotionBody.Substring(300, promotionBody.Length - 1));
    }
    else if (promotionBody.Length > 200)
    {
        message.Add(promotionBody.Substring(0, 99));
        message.Add(promotionBody.Substring(100, 199));
        message.Add(promotionBody.Substring(200, promotionBody.Length - 1));
    }
    else if(promotionBody.Length > 100)
    {
        message.Add(promotionBody.Substring(0, 99));
        message.Add(promotionBody.Substring(100, promotionBody.Length - 1));
    }
    else
    {
        message.Add(promotionBody);
    }
    return message;
}
```

What I am trying to do is to get a 100 characters string and add it to list. Please tell me what's wrong here? or how can I achieve it.

Comment: i suggest using a loop to break it up. i.e. keep going until there's none left. this is too unwieldy.

Comment: could you please share an example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several issues with your code:

1) The signature of the `Substring` method is:

```
public string Substring(int startIndex, int length)
```

So the second argument is the length which is 100 in your case all the time, not 99, 199, 299, or 399 like your trying to do.

2) When you're trying to get the rest of the string all the way to the end, use the other signature without the length:

```
public string Substring(int startIndex)
```

This is much easier to read and write than having to calculate the length of the string which you're doing wrong anyway, because `promotionBody.Length - 1` will be beyond the length of the string when your `startIndex` is greater than zero, and you'll get an exception.

3) In your proposed answer, you caught the exception and added the remaining characters. Using exceptions for normal and predictable flow is very frowned upon, use standard flow checks instead:

```
private List<string> MakeCustomDataReadyForPromotion() {
    var setting = SettingsDbManager.Instance.GetSettingBaseOnTrackId(Settings.PromotionDetailsTrackId);
    var restaurantTitle = setting.PromotionTitle;
    var promotionBody = setting.PromotionBody;
    int chunkSize = 100;
    List<string> message = new List<string> {
        restaurantTitle
    };
    for (int i = 0; i < promotionBody.Length; i += chunkSize) {
        if (promotionBody.Length - i > chunkSize)
            message.Add(promotionBody.Substring(i, chunkSize));
        else
            message.Add(promotionBody.Substring(i));
    }
    return message;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was making mistake of considering the `length` parameter of the `Substring(index,length)` method as the end index. It is not the end index but length of the string you want to extract. Now I have found better solution:

```
private List<string> MakeCustomDataReadyForPromotion()
{
    var setting = SettingsDbManager.Instance.GetSettingBaseOnTrackId(Settings.PromotionDetailsTrackId);
    var restaurantTitle = setting.PromotionTitle;
    var promotionBody = setting.PromotionBody;
    var totalCharacters = promotionBody.Length;
    List<string> message = new List<string>
    {
        restaurantTitle
    };
    for (int i = 0; i < totalCharacters; i += 100)
    {
        try
        {
            message.Add(promotionBody.Substring(i, 100));
        }
        catch
        {
            message.Add(promotionBody.Substring(i, totalCharacters - i));
        }
    }
    return message;
}
```

This loop catches 100 character strings, and an exception is thrown when remaining characters are less than a 100. Then I add the remaining characters in the list.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
private List<string> MakeCustomDataReadyForPromotion()
    {
        // etc etc
        /// etc etc

        AddMessage(promotionBody, message);
    }

    private static void AddMessage(AddInCorrectObjectHere promotionBody, List<string> message)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < Math.Ceiling((decimal)promotionBody.Length / 100); i++)
        {
            message.Add(promotionBody.Substring(i, (i + 1) * 100 - 1));
        }
    }
```

WARNING: Untested code. Please make sure that it works even when the substring is between 0 and 99 even when the message length is less than 99 in length.