# What could be the best way of extracting substrings of varying length in c#

Tags: c#, string, substring

I looked up a lot and to be honest I even know how to do this but I want a smarter dynamic method in order to extract substrings of varying lengths from a string. For instance I have these 2 strings as follows 1. ML 49420220831LDHRJP 2. Y6456720220930RJPLDH so these strings should be divided into sub strings like for the first string its substrings should look like this ML, 494 (but this should have a whitespace in the beginning the 494 one), 20220832, LDH and lastly RJP same way for the second string it should be Y6, 4567, 20220930, RJP and lastly LDH.

Any input will be appreciated.

Comment: So what did you try, where did you fail?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Getting strings of specific length from a string of different length](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51796517/getting-strings-of-specific-length-from-a-string-of-different-length)

Comment: I tried using Substring(index, length) but then I'm literally putting integers like Substring(0,2) to extract first substring and did same for the rest but it doesn't seem to be a smart idea.

Comment: Perhaps you can make a method that creates substrings. It could take an array of integers as the parameter, where each `int` in the array defined the length of the next substring. Then you can start at index 0, and create substring of length `params[0]` and then repeat at index (0 + params[0]).

Comment: You need to figure out the actual pattern you need to follow for splitting the strings. If you can't figure it out, you won't be able to program it. You'll have to look at all your possible strings and figure that out. For example, you may know that for all of them you want to take all the letters and the first non-letter off the front ("ML " and "B6"). But your actual requirements aren't clear so there isn't much to help with. The answers you will get will be suggesting to use `substring` as you had mentioned.

Comment: If you know the last 6 characters will always be letters and that you will always take the first three and last three as two separate strings, that's another pattern you can use.

Comment: There is definitely a pattern of 1st substring being 2 char length , 2nd being 4 but first char may be a whitespace or not, then substring being 8 char length and last 2 substrings being 3 char length each.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
        int[] array = new int[] { 2, 4, 8, 3, 3 };
        List<string> someList = new List<string>();
        int j = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i ++)
        {
            string str = delta.Substring(j, array[i]);
            someList.Add(str);
            j += str.Length;
        }
```